# How to can I get the names of my mysql table columns

Tags: php, mysql

RESOLVED
I have used the answer from alfasin, but as that gave me WAY too much information, i wrote a little script to just get the field names. As the field names apeared first, it was rather simple:

```
  $here = array();
  $SQL = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM User";
    foreach($conn->query($SQL) as $row) {
      $here[] = $row[0];
    }
  echo '<pre>';print_r($here);echo '<pre>';
```

This left me with the new array `$here` containing the column names, hope this helps someone in the future :)

---

Original question:
Let me clarify a bit, I have a mysql table and I'm trying to select * from it, and display the result in an html list `<ol>`. I can manage to grab the row data JUST FINE, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab the table column names, in order to match them up with the row, respectively. this is my code that is grabbing the row data:

```
//get those results
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT *
 FROM User
 WHERE Owner = '".$owner."'";
  foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
  //split array in half
  $hax = count($row);
  $halfHax = $hax / 2;
   //set up a for loop to give results
    $u = 1;
      for($i = 2; $i <= $halfHax; $i++){
        echo $row[$u].'<br>';
        $u++;
      }
   }
```

this is giving me all the result where `Owner == $owner` just like it should, but I would like the column names to list with those, I could hard-code it out, but more columns may be added/changed so I would rather not. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to try fetching an associative array to keep column names as the keys of your array. Are you using PDO? `fetch(PDO::fetch_assoc)`

Comment: @showdev I have gotten too much harrasment about mysql_* functions to use anything but ;)

Comment: Look at the solution given at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853094/how-to-get-the-columns-names-along-with-resultset-in-php-mysql

Comment: @user2041082 I dont want to use mysql_* functions

Comment: I would advise against using $owner in query() like that, for security reasons.. if it's originating from user input, this is a textbook SQL injection..

Comment: @omercnet i thought about that, but that variable is being passed from ajax via a js onclick event, no actual user input. does that still need sanitized?

Comment: @JohnDoe yes of course, anything that comes from the browser can be manipulated, even though it's JS, your script still gets that input from a $_POST or $_GET which is controlled by the user

Comment: you should avoid using unnecessary queries.. please see solution by @showdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: That gives me A LOT of information about the columns, any chance you know a way i can single out just the solumn names?

Comment: Figured out a solution to my first issue with this solution, posted the solution in my original question.

Comment: you should avoid using unnecessary queries.. please see solution by @showdev

Comment: @omercnet I did try it, but it did not work for me in the end, just adding a new SQL query did.

Comment: In addition, this way made it easier to create my list.

Answer (score 3):

Fetch rows as associative arrays in order to keep your column names as array keys.
Here's my suggestion:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM User WHERE Owner = :owner";
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':owner' => $owner);

while($row=$sth->fetch(PDO::fetch_assoc) as $row) {
  //split array in half
  $hax = count($row);
  $halfHax = $hax / 2;
  //set up a for loop to give results
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'='.$value.'<br />';
  }
```

}

To just list the column names:

```
array_keys($row);
```

Comment: great solution! just added parameterized query support for improved security against SQL injections

Comment: Awesome, definitely a good idea. Look into `prepare` if you haven't already.

Comment: I edited your answer to include prepare, please approve the edit

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to **SHOW COLUMNS** at the [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) if you want more information about the columns.

But I'd suggest using [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and then using [foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to get the column name and it's value, for each row.

Comment: That was the first thing i thought of! but i would rather not use mysql_* functions... I'm trying to get out of that habbit and use PDO

Comment: @JohnDoe, omercnet said `mysqli` not `mysql`. There is nothing wrong with `mysqli`. It is recommended for new projects along with `PDO`.

Comment: @mike I think he wants to use PDO to enable support for multiple databases, and not just MySQL

Comment: @Mike you're right, after hours of code, it all just start to blend together.. my bad :P

Comment: @omercnet, even though that's a valid reason to choose PDO, I don't see anything that would indicate that this was one of the influencing factors in this particular case. The question is tagged only with `mysql` and no other DBMS. Correct me if I'm wrong.