# How to display query results in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know how to make a set query display, but I need to take an input, run a statement, and display the result. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<form name="form3" method="post" action="sqlexp.php">
  <input name="sqlstatement" type="text" id="sqlstatement" style="width: 340px;">
  <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
ob_start();
$host     = "localhost";    // Host name 
$username = "root";         // Mysql username 
$password = "Passw0rd";     // Mysql password 
$db_name  = "time_tracker"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $sqlstatement
$sqlstatement = $_POST['sqlstatement']; 

// runs statement
$sql = " $sqlstatement ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;
echo $result;
ob_end_flush();
```

I also want to make the statements read only so nobody can mess with my tables.
im a little new to this i might need some extra explaining

Comment: Fetch the result. You shouldn't pass SQL statements through a form input, very insecure. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php You should update your driver to `mysqli` or `pdo`, not `mysql_*`. Additionally variables don't need to be in double quotes.

Comment: that is where the read only part comes in and this will only be available to admins

Comment: Is the question how to output the query results or how to make users only execute `select`s?

Comment: both but my priority is output

Comment: You should [stop using a database API that has been deprecated for 5 years, and doesn't even work in a current version of PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: What is failing and producing error ?

Comment: nothing is i just dont know how to further go about what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve column names along with the result set, look at this SO question: [How to get the columns names along with resultset in php/mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853094/how-to-get-the-columns-names-along-with-resultset-in-php-mysql)

Specifically this code snippet should help you print out the results:

```
// Print the column names as the headers of a table
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $field_info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    echo "<th>{$field_info->name}</th>";
}

// Print the data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $_column) {
        echo "<td>{$_column}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Now, that said, **please be very, very careful before proceeding.** It looks like you're unfamiliar with PHP, and what you're attempting is very dangerous as it opens up a classic SQL injection vulnerability: https://xkcd.com/327/

You could restrict the possibility of damage by restricting the database permissions to read-only for the user you're logging in as ($username and $password). Do NOT login as root - never!

If this form is only available to Admins, why not give them a true SQL IDE like Toad or SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: My first instinct was to say "Stop what you're doing, you could do more harm than good", but sometimes we can't tell that to our bosses. My only hope is that this isn't for a public facing website, and that your user base has only good intentions.

Comment: this is internal for the company i work for i have an admin column in my user table and verification to go along with that.

Comment: when i try var dump i get `resource(4) of type (mysql result)` when running `SELECT * FROM Users`

Comment: @RobertHolden did you try the code from the SO I linked to? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1853101/918287

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dear Try this code. I hope it will work for you

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="Passw0rd"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="time_tracker"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($host, $username,"")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $sqlstatement
if(isset($_POST['create']))
{
$sqlstatement=$_POST['sqlstatement']; 
echo $sqlstatement;
}

ob_end_flush();
?>

 <form name="form3" method="post" action="">
<input name="sqlstatement" type="text" value="Test" style="width: 340px;">
<input type="submit" name="create" value="Create">
</form>
```

Comment: this is what i already have. if i were to put an sql statement in the text field i want it to return a query

Comment: in other word if i were to open phpmyadmin and run a select statement on a table i would see the query no matter which table i selected. is there a way to automatically get column headings based on the query i ran?

Comment: But without insert query how data insert into database and select query not possible tell me you want to insert text field value into database too...??

Answer (score 0):

First of you should NEVER pass SQL statements through a form input, it is very insecure. Second use the new `mysqli_*` or pdo.

Instead you can have a form that enables you to do something, for example create a contact.

You can have a simple form that looks to this:

```
<form method="post" action="link/to/script.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
    <input type="email" name="email"/>
    <input type="submit" name="create_contact"/>
</form>
```

Now the PHP script to create the contact:

```
if(isset($_POST['create_contact'])){ // if submit is set, then create contact
  $firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
  $lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];

  $sql="INSERT INTO contacts (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; //query here. The `?` are placeholders
  $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql); //prepare query
  $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email); // In the first argument, `s` stands for string, there is also `i` for integer
                                                           // Set paramters
  $stmt->execute();  //Execute the query                                                          
}
```

Now to get a list(array) of contacts in you database and output them.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM cotacts"; // SQL statement
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); //Do query
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //Fetch array

//Output array
foreach($row as $contact){
    echo $contact['firstname'];
    echo $contact['lastname'];
    echo $contact['email'];
    }
```

Never allow a user or anyone to run a SQL that they will be typing out them selves.

Answer (score 0):

Within your database create a privileges column and then on the SQL query use WHERE AND, as a suggestion PDO statments are easy enough to master and more secure than regular SQL

```
$query = "SELECT type, name FROM something WHERE user = :user AND privlages = 2 ";
$query_params = array(':user' => $user ); 
try{$stmt = $db->prepare($query); $yourArgs= $stmt->execute($query_params);} 
catch(PDOException $ex){} 
$stmt->execute();
$yourArgs = $stmt->fetchAll();
//call array wherever
foreach($yourArgs as $key => $row){
   $type = $row['type'];
   $name = $row['name'];
}
```

In addition, to create a PDO connection:

```
 $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true); 
 try {$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);} 
 catch(PDOException $ex) {die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());}   
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```