# Get columns names when result set (stored procedure) is empty (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have come across a situation where the columns generated by my `stored procedure` are dynamic. I want to know, do we have any method to get the columns names of a result set when the result set returned by stored procedure is empty in Laravel?

I can easily access columns by iterations over the result set when it is not empty but is there any method to access the column names when the data is empty?

That's what I mean to be exact.

```
 $data = Schema::getColumnListing("call conflictReport(123,'2016-08-01 09:00:31','2016-08-01 09:00:31')");
```

My procedure takes 3 parameters as in parameters.

When the result set is empty, I can't access the column names. I am using `getColumnListing` of Laravel.

Comment: May be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853094/how-to-get-the-columns-names-along-with-resultset-in-php-mysql

Comment: `mysql_fetch_field` ?

Comment: @MageshKumaar using laravel and calling it via stored procedure..

Comment: @1000111 I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: I got confused with `any to print the columns names in PHP?`. Maybe you should replace it with `Laravel 5.2/stored procedure`.

Comment: @MageshKumaar done already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve column definition for stored procedure result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368864/retrieve-column-definition-for-stored-procedure-result-set)

Comment: @apokryfos using mysql not sql server..using laravel

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it directly with PDO. With Laravel, you should be able to us the [getPdo()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/MySqlConnection.html#method_getPdo) function of your `MySQLConnection` object.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'xxxxxxxx');

$stmt = $pdo->query('select * from mytable where false');
$colCount = $stmt->columnCount();
for ($col = 0; $col < $colCount; ++$col) {
    print_r($stmt->getColumnMeta($col));
}
```

I tested and found this works with a `CALL` query too:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('call myproc()');
```

Basically any statement with a result set has column metadata.

See [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) for more information.

Comment: updated the question basically I am accessing stored procedure using laravel

Comment: we use this -->     $data = Schema::getColumnListing("call conflictReport(123,'2016-08-01 09:00:31','2016-08-01 09:00:31')");   in laravel to call procedure..did not work though

Comment: I'm not a Laravel user, but it took me about 5 seconds to find the docs for [`getColumnListing()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_getColumnListing) and see that it takes a table name as an argument, not a SQL statement. I think you should read the docs more carefully.

Comment: He just said that he needs returning columns names from stored procedure, not a table. I deleted my answer.