# How to get the header value on getcsv in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to get the value of column header in getcsv but I can't.

Example inputs:

> Name , Address , Age
>  John , California, 26
>  Michael, L.A   , 29

If I am in row2 column2, I want to get the name of header which is **Address**. But my code returns as L.A.

This is my code:

```
   <?php
    echo '<table class="tbl">'; 
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {  
        $col    = count($data);  
        $header = $data[0]; //I AM SUPPOSED to get this value but this returns to the current cell and not the column header.
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($c=0; $c < $col; $c++) { 
            $cell   = esc_html( $data[$c] );
            $colnum = $c + 1;
            if( $row == 0)
            {    
                echo "<td  style='text-transform:uppercase;'><br><br>". 
                        "<b>{$cell}</b></td>"; 
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "<td>{$cell} = {$header}</td>";  //{$row} = {$colnum} 
            } 
        }
        echo '</tr>'; 
        $row++; 
    }  
    echo '</table>';
```

Based on the inputs and code above, here is the output:

> **Name , Address , Age**
>  John = John , California = California , 26 = 26
>  Michael= Michael , L.A = L.A  , 29 = 29

I am supposed to get the header value of each column as shown below:

> **Name , Address , Age**
>  John = Name , California = Address , 26 = Age
>  Michael= Name , L.A = Address   , 29 = Age

Comment: Do you want these headers `Name, Address, Age`?

Comment: This may have been answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853094/how-to-get-the-columns-names-along-with-resultset-in-php-mysql

Comment: Yes.. I want to get these headers per row. because I want to compare the header in CSV and my header in database

Comment: @norcal I am using CSV and not database.. They different in fetching records.. In CSV, row1 is the header..

Comment: You can do one thing, In your code where you check for `$row==1` at that place you can store the value of header in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better answer, but the code below will work.

Your CSV data is being returned in the manner below:

```
Array ( [0] => Name [1] => Address [2] => Age )  
Array ( [0] => John [1] => California [2] => 26 ) 
Array ( [0] => Michael [1] => L.A [2] => 29 )
```

**Updated Answer**

```
<?php
     $headerValues  = array();
     $counter = 0;
     $row = 0;
     if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<table class="tbl">'; 
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {  
            // You need to grab the header values on first iteration
            if ($counter == 0) {
              // store them in an array
              $headerValues = $data;
              // increment counter
              $counter++;                  
            }                

            $col    = count($data); 
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($c=0; $c < $col; $c++) {
                // grab column name here
                $headerName = $headerValues[$c]; 
                $cell   = $data[$c];
                $colnum = $c + 1;
                if( $row == 0)
                {                    
                    echo "<td  style='text-transform:uppercase;'><br><br>". 
                            "<b>{$headerName}</b></td>"; 
                }
                else
                { 
                    echo "<td>{$cell} = {$headerName}</td>";  //{$row} = {$colnum} 
                } 
            }
            echo '</tr>'; 
            $row++; 

        }  

        echo '</table>';
    }
    ?>
```